# What is the correct way to merge several javascript scripts into one? On the example of Google translator (https://translate.google.com/?hl=ru)

Tags: javascript

When combining 4 scripts into one, there are problems, separately the scripts work in google translate. I would be grateful for a hint on how to do everything right.

Step #1: activate ('ita-kd-icon-button ita-kd-inputtool-icon ita-kd-small ita-kd-single') - "Enable Handwriting"

```js
function setValues(el, values) {
    el.value = "";
    el.focus();
    el.click();
    el.autocomplete = "on";
    console.log(el.value);
}
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ita-kd-icon-button ita-kd-inputtool-icon ita-kd-small ita-kd-single');
const timeout = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(setValues, timeout * i, elements[i], i);
}
```

Step #2 Substitute the text in the text area

```js
function setValues(el, values) {
    el.value = "";
    el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key':'Shift'} ));
    el.focus();
    el.click();
    el.value = "привет привет ахахахахха.";
    el.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false, inputType: 'insertFromPaste'}));
    el.autocomplete = "on";
    console.log(el.value);
}
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('er8xn');
const timeout = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(setValues, timeout * i, elements[i], i);
    }
```

Step #3 close the field ('ita-kd-img ita-hwt-close') "Enable Handwriting"

```js
function setValues(el, values) {
    el.value = "";
    el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key':'Shift'} ));
    el.focus();
    el.click();
    el.value = "привет привет ахахахахха.";
    el.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false, inputType: 'insertFromPaste'}));
    el.autocomplete = "on";
    console.log(el.value);
}
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ita-kd-img ita-hwt-close');
const timeout = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(setValues, timeout * i, elements[i], i);
    }
```

Step #4 open ('mqNsCe tQlvad') History

```js
function setValues(el, values) {
    el.value = "";
    el.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {'key':'Shift'} ));
    el.focus();
    el.click();
    el.value = "привет привет ахахахахха.";
    el.dispatchEvent(new InputEvent('input', {bubbles: true, cancelable: false, inputType: 'insertFromPaste'}));
    el.autocomplete = "on";
    console.log(el.value);
}
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('mqNsCe tQlvad');
const timeout = 1000;
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(setValues, timeout * i, elements[i], i);
    }
```

Comment: your snippets don't do anything because there's no elements

Comment: enclose each script in an IIFE for each of them, since all your function names are the same .

Comment: oh, wait, step 2 needs to wait for step 1 to finish, and so on, right

Answer (score 0):

First, create this helper function

```
const wait = n => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, n));
```

Now, wrap each step in a function, like this (call them `step1` `step2`, `step3` and `step4`)

```
const step1 = async() => {
    function setValues(el, values) {
        el.value = "";
        el.focus();
        el.click();
        el.autocomplete = "on";
        console.log(el.value);
    }
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ita-kd-icon-button ita-kd-inputtool-icon ita-kd-small ita-kd-single');
    const timeout = 1000;
    for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        await wait(timeout);
        setValues(elements[i], i);
    }
};
```

When you've done all that, you can simply execute the sequence like

```
step1().then(step2).then(step3).then(step4);
```

Comment: If everyone understood correctly.
When I type in the console, the error is: Uncaught ReferenceError: step1 is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: if step1 is not defined, you did it wrong

Comment: I take it you created step1 "in the console" too

Comment: Yes, I did it in the console

Where could you go wrong in the first step?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Drago_King/q4y53phr/ 
Here is a visual representation of how the script was written in the console.
google chrome browser

Comment: Yeah, step1 you did right - copy/paste made that easy - but then you completely screwed up making the SAME changes for steps 2, 3 and 4. Also, the error is `redeclaration of timeout` not that `step1 is not defined` ... check the difference between your step 1 and the code in the answer - then you'll see what you did wrong @DragoKing